# Image aspect ratio not working in slick slider

Tags: wordpress, slick.js, aspect-ratio

I have a slick slider in my WordPress site, using bg images on the slick-slide.

I need to keep them at a set aspect ratio, which I know how to do and normally works great, but it's proving to be tricky on the slick slider.

When I add my usual aspect ratio 'padding-top' to the slide, It just makes the slide/image really long: you can see this here: https://codepen.io/pixelboutiqueuk-the-lessful/pen/zYrZJgQ?editors=0110

**html:**

```
<div class="feature-block" data-aos="fade" style="background-color:<?php echo $bg_color; ?>">
  <ul class="slider fancy-slider" id="feature-block-slider" data-aos="fade">
    <li class="slick-slide" data-aos="fade" style="background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1568819646610-2f8982dd0c71?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1868&q=80');"><div class="overlay"></div></li>
        <li class="slick-slide" data-aos="fade" style="background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1586220778893-1fae18067543?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80');"><div class="overlay"></div></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="content-wrapper" data-aos="fade">
    <h2 class="title">Static content box</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla tincidunt vel risus id ornare. Sed at posuere turpis. Sed eu convallis diam. Duis vitae lectus finibus, luctus ante in, elementum mauris. Duis nec diam luctus, tristique tortor vel, pellentesque sapien. Nulla tincidunt tempus felis, vehicula interdum mi eleifend a. Duis non ante porttitor, luctus ligula eu, cursus sapien. Mauris varius lobortis mi sit amet euismod. Integer id leo tempus velit accumsan tempor sed id lectus. Nulla imperdiet iaculis erat nec placerat. Vivamus tincidunt ipsum eu lorem vestibulum, euismod ultricies nunc congue.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.feature-block {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 60px !important;
  padding-right: 60px !important;
}

ul#feature-block-slider {
  margin-right: 47px;
  width: 50%;
}

li.slick-slide {
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
}

.slick-arrow {
  font-size: 0;
  position: absolute;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $slideshow = $('.slider').slick({
    infinite: true,
    mobileFirst: true,
    vertical: false,
    fade: false,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 5000,
    speed: 2000,
    dots: false,
    arrows: true,
    pauseOnHover: true,
    slidesPerRow: 1,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    adaptiveHeight: false
  });
  
  $('.slider').click(function(e) {
       var pWidth = $(this).innerWidth();
       var pOffset = $(this).offset(); 
       var x = e.pageX - pOffset.left;
 
      if(pWidth/2 > x) {
        $slideshow.slick('slickNext');
      } else if(pWidth/2 < x) {
        $slideshow.slick('slickPrev');
      }
  });
  
    $('.slider').click(function(e) {
       var pWidth = $(this).innerWidth();
       var pOffset = $(this).offset(); 
       var x = e.pageX - pOffset.left;
 
      if(pWidth/2 > x) {
        $slideshow.slick('slickNext');
      } else if(pWidth/2 < x) {
        $slideshow.slick('slickPrev');
      }
  });
  
  $('.slider').on('mousemove', function(e){
       var pWidth = $(this).innerWidth();
       var pOffset = $(this).offset(); 
       var x = e.pageX - pOffset.left;
 
      if(pWidth/2 > x) {
        $('.slick-slide').css('cursor','url(https://i.ibb.co/qR2mDmM/slider-arrow-left.png), pointer');
      } else if(pWidth/2 < x) {
        $('.slick-slide').css('cursor','url(http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/closedhand.cur), pointer');
      }
  });
});
```

When I add the padding-top to the slider itself, this looks like the right size, but then the slide image is pushed out of view (to the bottom).

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Percent on a padding is defined by the relative parent width, in tthis case `div.slick-track`.
An easy way to fix that is to apply the padding somewhere else :

```
li.slick-slide {
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
li.slick-slide .overlay {
  padding-top: 56.25%;
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly in codepen, but for some reason didn't play ball in my actual code. Wrapping my slider in a div seemed to fix that for some reason. Thank you :)